# If empty message appearing all the time for drop down

Tags: php, mysql

In my drop down box, it is a required field but even if something has been selected the validation message appears,

```
 if(empty($data['department']) || strlen($data['department']) )
    {
    $err[] = "ERROR - Please enter the department you are applying for.";
    }
```

which is pulled from

```
$insert = "INSERT into users
`department`,  VALUES ( '$data[department] )";
```

HTML:

```
<td>Department<span class="required">*</span> </td>
        <td><select name="department"  id="department">

            <option value="" selected></option>

            <option <? if($department == '1') { ?> selected <? } ?>   
 value="1">1</option>

            <option <? if($department== '2') { ?> selected <? } ?> value="2">2   
  </option>

            <option <? if($department == '3') { ?> selected <? } ?> 
 value="3">3</option>


            </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (empty($data['department']))
{
    $err[] = "ERROR - Please enter the department you are applying for.";
}
```

You don't need to check for strlen if the variable is empty

Answer (score 1):

This line is contradictory and will always return true.

```
empty($data['department']) || strlen($data['department'])
```

Just use the first half and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to remove `selected` from `<option value="" selected>` and try because, if the `$department==1` then you have two `selected` options which could be causing the error.